# Solve this annoying access file error

Tags: ms-access

I appologise for the rather vague title of this thread, but I'm not able to be more specific, you'll understand why in just a sec...

When I try open my Access file (Access 2010), I regularly get this error message..

```
Microsoft Access a rencontré un problème et doit être fermé. Nous vous prions de nous excuser pour le désagrément encouru.

Les informations sur lesquelles vous travailliez peuvent avoir été perdues. Microsoft Access peut tenter de compacter et de réparer la base de données ouverte.

Nous avons créé un rapport d'erreurs que vous pouvez envoyer pour nous aider à améliorer la qualité de Microsoft Access. Nous traiterons vos rapports confidentiellement et anonymement.
```

Sorry that it is in french, basically it has found an error in my file, and wants to close and send a message to MS.

I opened a link to look at the full error report (this is available at the bottom of the popup), these are the contents...

```
AppName: msaccess.exe      AppVer: 14.0.6024.1000     AppStamp:4d83e4fc
ModName: vbe7.dll      ModVer: 7.0.16.19      ModStamp:4d430aec
fDebug: 0       Offset: 00023081
0x0000000000000000  Address: 0x0000000065023081
```

If I keep followng the links it finaly get something 'usefull'

```
System Information
Windows NT 5.1 Build: 2600
CPU Vendor Code: 756E6547 - 49656E69 - 6C65746E
CPU Version: 000106C2  CPU Feature Code: BFE9FBFF


Module 1
MSACCES
Image Base: 0x0000000030000000  Image Size: 0x00d5d000
Checksum: 0x00d5e000    Time Stamp: 0x4d83e4fc
Version Information
```

... or maybe not !

The info is saved in a file temp\6718937.cvr  which is just goobledegook of glyphs and non printable characters.

Anyway I guess I know what the problem is.

I am developping this solution and have a large amount of VBA code inside, some of it doesn't work properly... yet.

So I have to spend ages installing/starting up 2007, compact and repair, then go back to 2010 (another wait to install/start up), and my file is miraculously functioning.

I regularly perform a compat and repair on the main file using the button that is available in Access 2010 (I even have access to perform this whenever the DB is shutdown), but either it doesn't work properly or I'm doing something wrong?

I know that when I open this file in Access 2007 (before performing the repair) it helpfully informs me that this file contains suspect vba code that could damage my pc. Obviously I know this file won't damage my pc... or at least I hope not ;) . It then gives me the option of opening the file anyway and ignoring the potential dangers.

Where is this option in access 2010 (or is this MS trying to protect users from their own stupidity... bit like Apple).

Or is there some other solution to this problem in Access 2010

Comments,
suggestions, 
finger pointing and 'its your fault' may be accepted as a solution.

Thanks in advance

David

Edit 1:

After the response I just thought I should add that I could use Access 2007 all the time. The issue here is that there are other members of the team who only use Access 2010, so that is the 'standard' install.

As I say in response to the first answer given, what I want is to have the option to 'run the file even though the internal script may be dangerous' this option seems to have dissappeared in the 2010 version.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some corruption in the Access file

Create a new Access file.

Import all the tables, queries, etc. into the new file.

Comment: I expect that that is what the 'compact and repair' thing does behind the scenes, The issue for me is that I have to perform this 3 or 4 times each week in Access 2010, if however I open the same file in Access 2007 it gives me the option to select for 'I understand the risk, let me run the file anyhow'. What I really need is for enabling the same option in Access 2010.